# How to prove this trigonometric identity of sine of n angles as sum?

Tags: trigonometry

How can we prove
$ sin (A^1 + A^2 + ... + A^n) = cos A^1 . cos (A^2) ... cos (A^n)  [ S_1 - S_3 + S_5 ... ] $
where $S_n$ denotes sum of tangents of angles taken n at a time. 
I tried proving it but failed. I can derive it easily for n = 2 and 3 but not for general case. Wikipedia has same kind of formula for tangent but it is not derived. 
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities
Please give a very simple detailed proof.

Comment: Do you think induction would be good to work out?

Comment: Wikipedia also says this for tge tangent formula but I tried it but failed to prove the inductive step .

Answer (score 2):

$$
\sin(A^1+\ldots +A^n) = Im(e^{i(A^1+\ldots +A^n)}) \\
= Im(e^{iA^1}\cdot \ldots \cdot e^{iA^n})\\
= Im\left(\prod\left(\cos(A^j) + i\cdot\sin(A^j)\right)\right)
$$

Multiplying out the big product, we get a product of sines and cosines.  Each term will be either pure real or pure imaginary, more specifically it will be a  product of cosines and sines times $i^k$ where $k$ is the number of sines in the product.  Since 
$$
\tan(A) = \frac{\sin(A)}{\cos(A)}
$$
we can pull out the product of all the cosines, and we're left with tangents where the sines were.  Since we're only interested in the imaginary part, we get only the terms where the number of tangents are odd, and with a plus sign if the number of tangents is congruent to $1$ mod $4$, negative if the number of tangents is congruent to $3$ mod $4$

Comment: Can you please prove this without using complex numbers ie by pure trigonometry or by induction

Comment: Yes, I can, but I don't want to take the time, I'm sorry.  I don't think an induction proof is very enlightening here, and I can't think of an enlightening trigonometric proof, either.  If you need a hint to prove it by induction, use the angle sum formula where one angle is $A^1$ and the other is $A^2+\ldots+A^n$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos A^j+i\sin A^j=\cos A^j(1+\tan A^j)\ \ \forall j\\\implies \prod_j(\cos A^j+i\sin A^j)=\prod_j\cos A^j.(1+i\tan A^j)\\\implies \cos(\sum_jA^j)+i\sin(\sum_jA^j)\\=\prod_j\cos A^j \{(1-S_2+S_4+\cdots+i^{2k}S_{2k})+i(S_1-S_3+S_5+\cdots +i^{2k}S_{2k+1})\}$$

$$\therefore \sin(\sum_jA^j)=(S_1-S_3+S_5+\cdots +i^{2k}S_{2k+1})$$

Comment: Can we prove this without using complex numbers ?

Comment: @RaghavSingal It will become too complex ;-) The induction step for the $m+1$ th step is too clumsy for human solving.

Comment: Isn't there any other method ?

Comment: @RaghavSingal Sorry! My knowledge is limited. But I don't know why you are not accepting this beautiful proof! Is it just curiosity for another proof, or you don't have a good correlation with complex numbers?

Comment: That is not the case I am familiar with the euler's formula but I don't understand the last step that you did .

Comment: @RaghavSingal Which line? From the first implication to the second implication?

Comment: Yes the second last line which is before therefore.

Comment: @RaghavSingal Sorry that was a typo! Now is my answer acceptable?

Comment: No not the typing error , I don't understand how did these terms of S come when inside sine and cosine angles are added ?

Comment: @RaghavSingal Why don't you try expanding $$\prod_j (1+i\tan A^j)$$ ? At least the first few terms?